# Adding Custom Markers to Custom Styled Google Maps API v3 for Wordpress website

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, google-maps-api-3

**Hi Everybody!**

I am trying to create a Custom Styled Google map using API v3. The map will eventually go on the following Wordpress page (310px x 537px blank space on right side of page): http://www.flatschicago.com/edgewater-chicago-apartments/

I have copied the JavaScript/HTML code from the *Google Maps Javascript API v3—Simple styled maps* page, and have change the color scheme to fit my websites overall theme. I have managed to format the code with the colors that I want, and I have managed to format the size of the map so it fits the space designated on my web page.

Here are the **3** things that I am having issues with:

1. I want to add 5+ custom plot markers to the map. Where do I add this code?
2. I want the street labels to appear on the map. Where do I add this code?
3. I tried adding the code in to my Wordpress page, but I did not work. Is there a certain part of the JavaScript/HTML code that I should only be adding?

Here is the code that I have so far.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Simple styled maps</title>
    <style>
    html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }

    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
    var map;
    var edgewater = new google.maps.LatLng(41.987245, -87.661233);

    var MY_MAPTYPE_ID = 'custom_style';

    function initialize() {

    var featureOpts = [

    {
      stylers: [
        { hue: '#3b3d38' },
        { visibility: 'simplified' },
        { gamma: 0.5 },
        { weight: 0.5 }
      ]
    },
    {
    featureType: 'poi.business',
      elementType: 'labels',
      stylers: [
        { visibility: 'off' }
      ]
    },
    {
      featureType: 'water',
      stylers: [
        { color: '#3b3d38' }
      ]
    }
    ];

      var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    center: edgewater,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, MY_MAPTYPE_ID]
    },
    mapTypeId: MY_MAPTYPE_ID
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);


    var styledMapOptions = {
    name: 'Custom Style'
    };

    var customMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(featureOpts, styledMapOptions);

    map.mapTypes.set(MY_MAPTYPE_ID, customMapType);
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
    </head>
    <body onload='intialize()'>
    <div id="map-canvas" style='width:310px; height:537px;'></div>
   </body>
   </html>
```

---

**1) Adding 5+ Custom Plot Markers**
The code I am referring to is from the following page: [page link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#complex_icons).
I understand that I need to add a marker image and long/lat for each location, but when I try and copy and paste this code into the code that I already have created, the map doesn't work. Where am I supposed to be copying and pasting this code? Do it go inside the function initialize() code? Or is it its own function? Very confused.

**2) Adding Street Labels**
The code I am referring to is from the *Google Maps Javascript API v3—Styled Maps* page.
All I want to do is to be able to see the street labels on the map. The code I am referring to is this. I tried putting this in to my code, but again, it didn't work. Is there a simply label like 'roads,' 'on' that gets these labels to work?

```
var styleArray = [
{
featureType: "all",
stylers: [
  { saturation: -80 }
]
},{
featureType: "road.arterial",
elementType: "geometry",
stylers: [
  { hue: "#00ffee" },
  { saturation: 50 }
]
},{
featureType: "poi.business",
elementType: "labels",
stylers: [
  { visibility: "off" }
]
}
];
```

**3) Add code to Wordpress page**
The map will eventually go on the */edgewater-chicago-apartments/* pahe.
The space that I left for the map is labeled 
    `<td class="neighborhood-map" rowspan="5"></td>` :

**If someone could please help me with this, I will be forever grateful. I feel like I am so close, yet these three things are holding me up and it is very frustrating. Anyone?**

Answer (score 1):

You need to have actual data (JSON format) to add the markers.  For example:

```
    // yourJsonData = data in valid JSON format
for ( i = 0; i < yourJsonData.length; i++ ) {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(yourJsonData[ i ].lat, yourJsonData[ i ].long);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: yourURL + '/path-to-custom-markers/' + yourJsonData[ i ].icon,
        position: latlng,
        title: yourJsonData[ i ].title,
        html: '<div class="info-window">Your window text</div>'
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(this.html);
        infowindow.setOptions({maxWidth: 800});
        infowindow.open(map, this);
    });
}
```

This code loops an array (yourJsonData) that has values for latitude, longitude, etc.